# How can my selectbox display "nothing selected" when a value is empty?

Tags: php

Hi I have a select box which works fine. The value of `$person` is always selected.

```
                 <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="person">

                    <?php 
                    $pdo = Database::connect();
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id ASC';
                    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                        echo('<option');?>
                        <?php 
                        if ($person == $row['name']) 
                        echo 'selected '; 
                        echo('value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>');
                    }
                    Database::disconnect();
                    ?>
                    <option></option>
                    </select>
```

But what I do not achieve is: If `$person` is empty, then the box should display `nothing selected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should had a first option with an unvalid value like :

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="person">
<option value="0">Choose a person</option>
                <?php 
                $pdo = Database::connect();
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id ASC';
                foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                    echo('<option');?>
                    <?php 
                    if ($person == $row['name']) 
                    echo 'selected '; 
                    echo('value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>');
                }
                Database::disconnect();
                ?>
                <option></option>
                </select>
```

By doing this, if no field is selected, the first one will be display !

Comment: Thank you, this works fine. But now I have for options: Choose a person, Person 1, Person 2 and an empty field. Is it possible to remove the empty field?

Comment: You have the <option></option> at the end of your script that you have to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if person is empty, and if so, output an option tag with the required wording:

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="person">
    <?php 
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id ASC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<option';
        if ($person == $row['name']) 
             echo 'selected '; 
        echo 'value="'.$row['name'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    if(empty($person))
        echo '<option selected >nothing selected</option>';
    Database::disconnect();?>
</select>
```

On another note, having database code intertwined with html is hard to read and maintain, it would be better to separate this, either into separate files, or at least have all the db code at the top of the file, and only have layout logic in the html